# Gerbera is not compiling, problem with fmt template

Tags: templates

I get the following error building gerbera can anyone help?
thanks

```
/sources/gerbera/gerbera-1.11.0/src/database/sql_database.cc:417:43:   required from here
/usr/include/fmt/format.h:2826:36: error: no matching function for call to â€˜fmt::v8::formatter<SQLIdentifier>::format(const SQLIdentifier&, fmt::v8::basic_format_context<fmt::v8::appender, char>&)â€™
 2826 |       out = value_formatter_.format(map(*it), ctx);
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /sources/gerbera/gerbera-1.11.0/src/database/sql_database.h:42,
                 from /sources/gerbera/gerbera-1.11.0/src/database/sql_database.cc:32:
/sources/gerbera/gerbera-1.11.0/src/database/sql_format.h:45:10: note: candidate: â€˜template<class FormatContext> decltype (ctx.out()) fmt::v8::formatter<SQLIdentifier>::format(SQLIdentifier&, FormatContext&)â€™
   45 |     auto format(SQLIdentifier& tn, FormatContext& ctx) -> decltype(ctx.out())
      |          ^~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like line 45 of sql_formate.h is short a const statement:

auto format(const SQLIdentifier& tn, FormatContext& ctx) -> decltype(ctx.out())

thanks